# auto generate attachment file missing in wp_mail()

Tags: wordpress, email

I am trying to send a mail with an attachment which is generating automatically according to the subscription option. But every time the mail is being sent (in Spam) but the attachment is not. I searched to this topic here but all the solutions are related to the 'uploads' folder.

Here is my code ..

```
require ( ABSPATH . 'pdfcrowd.php');
                    try
                    {
                        // create an API client instance
                        $client = new Pdfcrowd("apiname", "apikay");

                        // convert a web page and store the generated PDF into a $pdf variable
                        $pdf = $client->convertFile( ABSPATH . 'invoice_html.php');

                        // set HTTP response headers
                        header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
                        header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
                       header("Accept-Ranges: none");
                       header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"invoice.pdf\"");

                        //$to = $invoice_email;
                        $to = "moyen@gmail.com";
                        $subject = "Invoice for your online package.";
                        $message = "Message Body Invoice for your online package. Invoice for your online package. Invoice for your online package";
                        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: My Site Name <uddin@gmail.com');
                        $attachments = $pdf;

                        // send the generated PDF
                        //echo $attachments;

                       $wp_mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );

                    }
                    catch(PdfcrowdException $why)
                    {
                        echo "Pdfcrowd Error: " . $why;
                    }
```

any help?

N.B:Since I managed to output the pdf file in the browser to save but I would like to save this pdf file in a directory and then will send as attachment. What will be the best with this code above ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to send the pdf in email by the following modification code below....

## 1. First I just save the converted pdf in the uploads folder then

## 2. I take the pdf for the attachments

```
require ( ABSPATH . 'pdfcrowd.php');
                    try
                    {
                    // create an API client instance
                    $client = new Pdfcrowd("apiname", "apikay");

                    // converted php file and store the generated PDF inside uploads

                    $fd = fopen( ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/invoice.pdf', 'wb');
                    $client->convertFile( ABSPATH . 'invoice_html.php', $fd );
                    fclose($fd);

                    // set HTTP response headers
                    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
                    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
                   header("Accept-Ranges: none");
                   //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"invoice.pdf\"");

                    //$to = $invoice_email;
                    $to = "moyen@gmail.com";
                    $subject = "Invoice for your online package.";
                    $message = "Message Body Invoice for your online package. Invoice for your online package. Invoice for your online package";
                    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: My Site Name <uddin@gmail.com');
         
     // take the file from the uploads folder
                    $attachments = array( ABSPATH . '/wp-content/uploads/invoice.pdf' );


                    // send the generated PDF
                    //echo $attachments;

                   $wp_mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );

                }
                catch(PdfcrowdException $why)
                {
                    echo "Pdfcrowd Error: " . $why;
                }
```